# How to fix pull-merge-push on GitHub after the fact

Tags: git, git-merge

I do not recall exact messages or why it happened, but when I tried to do a push my changes to the remote repo I got a message that said something like `tip/head pointers were not in sync`, and that I needed to pull first and then push.  I did that, and now here is what I have:

**Observe Current State:**

```
* commit 7f82d39
|     comment 3
|
*   commit f4d754b
|\  Merge: aadc751 328b900
| | 
| |     Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/myrepo
| |
| * commit 328b900
| | 
| |     comment 2
| |
* | commit aadc751
|/  
|       comment 1
|
* commit aa65fee
```

Note that I am the author of all those commits and no other author was involved.  I would like to rebase this in such a way that destroys whatever errant/unintentional changes GitHub had, and keeps only the commits made on my repo on my local machine. effectively merging the branches into one.  And then push that local repo back to GitHub  overwriting whatever GitHub had.

In other words, **I want to have a single branch line, without it splitting and merging, where I can discard or merge-in any GitHub-originated commits and use only my local repo as the one "true" branch, without losing anything.**

How?

I know a little bit about rebase, but want to make sure I don't mess this up.

Bonus:  What do I do next time the tips of repos do not match?

Comment: ...why? There seems to be no reason to worry about this?

Comment: This is strictly from aesthetics point of view . . . but I suppose you are right otherwise.

Comment: Doing git diff on any pair of branches aadc751 f4d754b 328b900 produces nothing, so it's just a wasted branch clutter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The steps are these:
1. Give your "one true branch" a name and check it out
2. Fix up your history
3. Apply that last commit you did after the merge

which translates to:

```
git checkout -b onetrue aadc751
git rebase 328b900
git cherry-pick 7f82d39
```

And you're done.  You now have a branch called "onetrue" that has the history you want.  If you like it, keep it.  If you perhaps had been using another branch that you don't want anymore, for example "master", you can delete it:

```
git branch -D master
```

If you want your new branch to now be called master, rename it:

```
git branch -m onetrue master
```

Answering the bonus, to avoid this in future include the "rebase" flag when pulling:

```
git pull --rebase
```

Comment: great, it worked!  Thanks.  I can't vouch for `git pull --rebase` though, as when I did all the rebasing, I was not able to pull normally.  I was getting this message: `There is no tracking information for the current branch.  Please specify which branch you want to merge with.` That's where I just pushed my `onetrue` to GitHub using `--force`, so the world is back in order.

Comment: pull = fetch + merge.  Since you're on a newly created branch, git is simply saying it doesn't know which remote branch you wanted to merge with.  That pairing of a local branch with a corresponding remote one is called "tracking", and its purely a convenience to save you some typing. You can see/modify your tracking relationships by looking in the .git/config file in your repo.